# Does my question belong here or should it be migrated elsewhere?

Tags: discussion, migration

I asked [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/47238/2414) several days ago and the question only has 5 views (probably several, maybe even all of which are me).  So I'm wondering if the low views means the question is better off elsewhere, such as on SuperUser as its relation to emacs is too tangential?

Should this question be migrated to another site?

Answer (score 1):

I think the challenge you're facing is that you have an esoteric problem in a setup that very few people have to deal with.  Making matters worse is that it take a long time to explain the problem, so you're likely to lose readers along the way.

As for the number of views, I think your question title highlights the esoteric part ("VNC from Mac to Centos 6"... [sweet cuppin' cakes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0SLA57pppzI)), so most people skip it.

If you want to keep the question here, make sure you highlight the part that is about Emacs.  If you'd rather we migrate it, please say so (and say where you think it makes more sense).

Answer (score 0):

While your question is on-topic, your problem is at least partly with the keyboard configuration at the X11 level, since `xev` doesn't give the output that you'd expect. Answering your question probably requires some knowledge of VNC. You're more likely to find knowledgeable people on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

A moderator can migrate your question if you want. Just flag it and ask.